# Data.table and variables in R

Tags: r, variables

```
cad <- data.table(name)

y <- colnames(cad)[1]

cad <- add_row(cad, y = 100)
```

> Error: New rows can't add columns.
> x Can't find column `y` in `.data`.

Comment: It's alright to post code but you should explain the problem in words.

Answer (score 1):

It needs evaluation to get the value

```
library(data.table)
library(tibble)
add_row(cad, !! y := 100)
```

-output

```
#   col1 col2
#1:    1    6
#2:    2    7
#3:    3    8
#4:    4    9
#5:    5   10
#6:  100   NA
```

#### data

```
cad <- data.table(col1 = 1:5, col2 = 6:10)
y <- colnames(cad)[1]
```